# Unable to find jar files for tElasticsearch Index and Elasticsearch Indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, talend

I am running a job which puts a `Json` file on my locally installed `Elasticsearch` server and I have used a `tJAVA` component, code has the URL and parameters to be sent. I'm unable to `POST` data with this way. I researched online and found that `tElasticsearch Index` and `Elasticsearch Indexing` can be added to component list to make a proper connection but unable to find it. What jars are required for this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Two jar files are needed for it.

> elasticsearch and lucene-core jar files

They can be found the folder where elasticseach was installed. Copy these files to the tElasticSearch componant folder. Rename the jar files to remove the version.

Good practices are mentioned [here](http://spring-webservice-2-step-by-step.blogspot.in/2014/01/talend-elasticsearch-indexing-tutorial.html).

Comment: Talend exchange is not working correctly, and I had to install the plugin manually, So I do not have the two jar files at all. Where can I download them

Comment: They can be found in the root folder of the elasticsearch installation folder.

Comment: There is nothing. The Exchange link does not work and in the component they are not

Comment: or do you mean instalation folder of the the ElasticSearch server?

Comment: I managed to get it to work, but I am getting an exception. nonodeavailableexception: none of the configured nodes are available. I've set the cluste.name to the same value as it is defined in Elastic config file. What am I missing here

Comment: I got it. I was using the HTTP instead of the TCP port